# How do I simply Color-Code a code block in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a code block on a website which shows off some of my various HTML/CSS components, and I want it to be color coded; however, I find that this process is extremely tedious, and I was wondering if there is a faster way to do it.

For example, on [Bootstrap 5's buttons page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/), there contain various code blocks that relate to the displayed buttons; however, the way these code blocks are implemented are very messy. Here's an example of one:

```
<div class="highlight"><pre class="chroma"><code class="language-html" data-lang="html"><span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">button</span> <span class="na">type</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;button&#34;</span> <span class="na">class</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;btn btn-primary&#34;</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>Primary<span class="p">&lt;/</span><span class="nt">button</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>
<span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">button</span> <span class="na">type</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;button&#34;</span> <span class="na">class</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;btn btn-secondary&#34;</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>Secondary<span class="p">&lt;/</span><span class="nt">button</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>
<span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">button</span> <span class="na">type</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;button&#34;</span> <span class="na">class</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;btn btn-success&#34;</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>Success<span class="p">&lt;/</span><span class="nt">button</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>
<span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">button</span> <span class="na">type</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;button&#34;</span> <span class="na">class</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;btn btn-danger&#34;</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>Danger<span class="p">&lt;/</span><span class="nt">button</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>
<span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">button</span> <span class="na">type</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;button&#34;</span> <span class="na">class</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;btn btn-warning&#34;</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>Warning<span class="p">&lt;/</span><span class="nt">button</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>
<span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">button</span> <span class="na">type</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;button&#34;</span> <span class="na">class</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;btn btn-info&#34;</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>Info<span class="p">&lt;/</span><span class="nt">button</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>
<span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">button</span> <span class="na">type</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;button&#34;</span> <span class="na">class</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;btn btn-light&#34;</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>Light<span class="p">&lt;/</span><span class="nt">button</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>
<span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">button</span> <span class="na">type</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;button&#34;</span> <span class="na">class</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">&#34;btn btn-dark&#34;</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>Dark<span class="p">&lt;/</span><span class="nt">button</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>
```

This piece of code above is how Bootstrap 5 styles it's code blocks (there is so many individual spans with different attributes that are used to color code various sections). **Is there any way to color-code a code-block in HTML without having to individually add attributes to multiple span tags?**

## **EDIT (My Solution):**

For anyone wondering how I solved this issue, I decided to use [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/).
It's super easy to use, and I just found a youtube video on how to implement it quickly into my HTML code. Thanks again for the suggestions everyone!

Comment: I believe you're referring to *syntax highlighting* and there are libraries that handle that that would save you a lot of headaches over doing it yourself. Otherwise, style as you see fit.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I don't think the OP wants the changes you made, and is referring to the underlying styling of what you edited. If you visit the Bootstrap page link and see the HTML for the example you'll see what the OP posted.

Comment: I do not understand what you call messy ? , is it that 2 classes is too many or messy ? but there is no span just a simple button.

Comment: Duct-tape suggestion: Copy and paste your code from Visual Studio into MS Word (lol) which will convert it to an RTF-like representation, then copy and paste from Word into any `contenteditable` element, then View Source to get the HTML all already coloured for you.

Comment: @j08691 , that is the plain code he referred too , i have no idea how he came up to copy/paste the code he shared

Comment: @G-Cyrillus My interpretation of the OP is that they’re referring to the original markup that you deleted so I rolled-back your edit.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Not quite. You had it edited down to `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>...` but the equivalent line on the Bootstrap site is actually `<span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">button</span> <span class="na">type</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">"button"</span> <span class="na">class</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">"btn btn-primary"</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>Primary<span class="p">&lt;/</span><span class="nt">button</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>`

Comment: oups, allright he just complains about the source code of the doc ... LOL He might want to use the `<xmp>` or `<plain>`  tag

Comment: Haha thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@j08691 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110429/how-do-i-simply-color-code-a-code-block-in-html/69110551#comment122146643_69110429), there are libraries that will do this for you.

Just one example:

You can use an off-the-shelf syntax highlighter like [shiki](https://github.com/shikijs/shiki) and a little javascript to convert markup in your page to a syntax colored version.

This snippet takes a second to do the conversion, presumably because of the external script, but you get the idea:

```js
shiki
  .getHighlighter({
    theme: 'nord'
  })
  .then(highlighter => {
    document.querySelectorAll('pre').forEach(element => {
      const language = element.dataset.lang || 'js';
      const code = highlighter.codeToHtml(element.innerText, language);
      element.innerHTML = code
    })
  })
```

```css
pre {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/shiki@0.9.10/dist/index.unpkg.iife.js"></script>

<pre>
function foo (arg1) {
  console.log('syntax highlighting is fun.');
}
</pre>

<pre data-lang="html">
&lt;button class="foo"&gt;This is a button&lt;/button&gt;
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments everyone. I will continue to examine and figure this out. I'm new to this. Thanks for the heads up about shiki. I'll try to implement it this weekend!